# How to have a duplicate a key in a Uri query string in Dart

Tags: google-maps, flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

## Application: Google maps static API

In order to add multiple markers, the docs says we just need to set multiple values of the `markers` query string

> Multiple markers may be placed within the same markers parameter as
> long as they exhibit the same style; you may add additional markers of
> differing styles by adding additional markers parameters.

I tried using the Uri lib like so:

```
 final url = new Uri(
      scheme: 'https',
      host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
      path: 'maps/api/staticmap',
      queryParameters: {
        'markers' : 'color:blue|label:C|1.015,1.054',
        'markers' : 'color:red|label:C|1.012,1.057',
      },
    );
 print(url.toString());
```

But dart would not allow that. Is there other method ?

What happens is that it shows only one marker. (The first)

Comment: can you try `:` instead of `=` after `'markers'`?

Comment: BTW, for searchability, I would recommend changing your question title to be about how to duplicate a key in a `Uri` query, not how to have a duplicate key in a map.  Otherwise you are falling into the classic X-Y problem where you've prematurely settled on a solution instead of solving your ultimate problem.

Comment: @jamesdlin Good idea, I updated the title

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A `Map` cannot contain duplicate keys.  However, `Uri`'s constructor does support generating querystrings with duplicate keys.  From [the documentation for `Uri`'s constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Uri/Uri.html):

> When `queryParameters` is used the query is built from the provided map.... A value in the map must be either a string, or an `Iterable` of strings, where the latter corresponds to multiple values for the same key.

So you could do:

```dart
final url = Uri(
  scheme: 'https',
  host: 'maps.googleapis.com',
  path: 'maps/api/staticmap',
  queryParameters: {
    'markers': [
      'color:blue|label:C|1.015,1.054',
      'color:red|label:C|1.012,1.057'
    ],
  },
);
print(url.toString());
```

which prints:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=color%3Ablue%7Clabel%3AC%7C1.015%2C1.054&markers=color%3Ared%7Clabel%3AC%7C1.012%2C1.057
```